# app crashes after loading screen unless launched through xcode

Tags: ios, swift

I am having a weird issue with the latest build of my app where it runs fine on my phone when I launch it through Xcode but if I launch it later by tapping the app Xcode installed on my phone it crashes immediately after the launch screen has been displayed.

So to be clear it runs fine on my iPhone when plugged in to my computer and launched from Xcode.

It crashes after the launch screen if not plugged in to my computer.

I recently upgraded to Swift 2 and this is the first time I've tried it on my phone since.

Any ideas as to what could be causing this problem? I have no idea how to debug it since the error only occurs not plugged in.

**Crash report from the device log:**

```
Date/Time:           2015-10-20 21:31:47.47 -0600
Launch Time:         2015-10-20 21:31:47.47 -0600
OS Version:          iOS 9.0.2 (13A452)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001007d0f5c
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x00000001007d0f5c 0x100690000 + 1314652
```

Comment: You can access your device crash logs from Xcode, check them and see what error you get

Comment: Update your question with details about the crash.

Comment: @Vladimir how do I go about accessing those crash logs?

Comment: window -> devices (or shift-cmd-2) and there you'll see "View device log" button

Comment: @JozemiteApps as I said it doesnt crash when I run it through xcode.

Comment: Use [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com).

Comment: You can launch it on the device and then connect debug in Xcode with "Attach to Process" . Just for debugging you can also add an empty view controller with a button that goes to your actual First VC. Then you will have time to connect in Xcode while still launching from the device. If it crashes before pushing the button, the problem is in AppDel, if it doesn't it's in ViewDidLoad of the first VC. You will now also have access to the normal debug workflow.

Comment: another note : Between Swift 1.2 and Swift 2.0 there have been some changes in AppDel. Maybe create a new empty project and compare. I myself have had crashes that only happen when building for release. So it would not surprise me if some weird compile error resulting from a bad migration only showed up when Xcode was not connected.

Comment: Symbolicate the crash log and see where in your Swift code the app is crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following Vladimir's instructions to view the device log I was able to pin point where the crash was happening.

`window -> devices (or shift-cmd-2) and there you'll see "View device log" button`

Comment: was it something that could happen to others? if so maybe explain it in your answer